# How restrictive is the restrict keyword?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following simple function

```
static inline void
minVec(const double *restrict v, double *restrict vmin, unsigned length){
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    vmin[i] = -v[i];
  return;
}
```

which compiles and runs just fine when I use it this way

```
double v[] = {1, 2, 3};
minVec(v, v, 3);
```

I've been led to believe that using `restrict` in this case only informs the compiler that each iteration of the loop is independent of the others, so the loop can be aggressively optimized. Is this the correct way of doing it or am I poking with some implementation-defined behaviour here?

Comment: `restrict` has requested that `vmin` and `v` are not equal. Violation of this is UB.

Answer (score 5):

The `restrict` keyword is purely an optimization hint: it allows the compiler to reorder reads/writes from/to the restricted pointers with all other memory accesses. This cannot be done if the compiler cannot prove that the memory behind a pointer can only accessed via that pointer.

So, if you say `restrict`, you effectively tell the compiler: "I assure you this pointer is the only one that points to this memory, please feel free to reorder. I am fully aware that blue elephants may appear if I am wrong, but I'm the human, I can't be wrong, bow before me."

This keyword is for the sake of the compiler, not for your sake!

Comment: Looking at what my function does, I don't think reordering hurts at all. Or maybe I just misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: @downhillFromHere Your function reads from `v[..]` and writes to `vmin[..]`. Obviously, if the two arrays are the same and these read and write operations are reordered, the end result is not going to be the same. Your use of `restrict` tells the compiler “go ahead, reorder if you want”. You are only lucky that your particular compiler, in the particular version you are using, with the optimization options you chose, did not reorder operations in a way that changed the result to something you didn't want.

Comment: In theory, `restrict` would not have to be only an optimization hint: it could be used to emit warnings for call that do not appear to respect the precondition of the function. In practice, it is not convenient for that, because the meaning of `restrict` is defined with respect to what the function does with the pointers. `f(t, t + 1)` is allowed for `f(restrict int *p, restrict int *q)` if `f` does not access both `*q` and `*(p+1)`, forbidden if it does. Passing `&G` is allowed only if `f` does not access `G` directly. http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/08/02/restrict-not-modular

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq I can imagine that this reordering might summon blue elephants when the objects v and vmin point at are overlapped. But if the two arrays are the same and therefore each loop iteration only read/write from/to a certain address, I don't see what could go wrong. In order to perform what the function is supposed to, each write operation has to be preceded by the corresponding read operation, which means the end result is going to be the same with or without `restrict` behaviour. Just my thoughts. Anyway thanks a lot for elaborating!

Answer (score 3):

The use of `restrict`keyword indicates that the source of the copy and the destination *shouldn't overlap*.  **It doesn't guarantee that source of the copy and destination *doesn't* overlap**. If it happens, program invokes *undefined behavior*, which is what happening in your case.

Comment: Do you mean that my code just invoked an undefined behaviour which happens to be the behaviour that I want?

Comment: @downhillFromHere; Yes.